# How to open Lightning record form in popUp modal on Button click in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

[image: Component Action]

html

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div style="display:inline-block;margin-left: 10px;">
            <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:account" 
                            alternative-text="Account"
                            title="Account"
                            size="medium">
            </lightning-icon>
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;margin-left: 5px;">
            <lightning-combobox name="progress" 
                                label="Accounts" 
                                value={filter} 
                                options={options}
                                onchange={comboBoxHandleChange}>
            </lightning-combobox>
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;float:right;margin-right: 
         10px;">
            <lightning-button label="New" onclick={accountCreateHandle}></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button label="Import"></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button label="Printable View" onclick={handlePDF}></lightning-button>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
            <p class="slds-border_bottom">{dataSize} item : Filtered by 
     {filter}</p>
            <lightning-datatable columns={columns} 
                                 data={accs} 
                                 hide-checkbox-column="true"
                                 key-field="id">
            </lightning-datatable>
            <template if:true={showRecScreen}>
                <lightning-record-form object-api-name={accountObject}
                                       fields={accountFields}
                                       onsuccess={handleAccountCreated} 
                                       columns="2">
                </lightning-record-form>
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';  // import object
import AC_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';  // import fields
import AC_WEBSITE from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Website';
import AC_NUMBER from '@salesforce/schema/Account.AccountNumber';
import AC_INDUSTRY from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Industry';
import AC_RATING from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Rating';
import AC_PHONE from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Phone';
import AC_TYPE from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Type';

export default class FslListViewCompo extends LightningElement {
    accountObject = ACCOUNT_OBJECT;  // object type
    accountFields = [AC_NAME, AC_WEBSITE,AC_NUMBER, AC_INDUSTRY, AC_RATING, AC_PHONE, AC_TYPE]; // fields to be showin in form
    showRecScreen = false;

    // shows toast message after account creation
    handleAccountCreated(){
        // Run code when account is created.
        const showSuccess = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success!!',
            message: 'Account has been created',
            variant: 'Success',
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(showSuccess);
    }

    accountCreateHandle(){
        this.showRecScreen = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am assuming the unmatched `</lightning-card>` is just a mistake in creating the snippet for this question?

Comment: I deployed this code on my scratch org and form is opening. no error. I have added this component on flexipage. Where you are trying to open this page?

Comment: @PhilW I have uploaded my whole html code and still the record form is not open.

Comment: @amitghadage I am trying to deploy it on lightning__AppPage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize the new native [lightning-modal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-modal/documentation) component. Here's the updated and fully functional code.

**Your updated component**

**fslListViewCompo.html**

```
<div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 5px">
  <lightning-combobox
    name="progress"
    label="Accounts"
    value={filter}
    options={options}
    onchange={comboBoxHandleChange}
  ></lightning-combobox>
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block; float: right; margin-right: 10px">
  <lightning-button label="New" onclick={showPopup}></lightning-button>
  <lightning-button label="Import"></lightning-button>
  <lightning-button
    label="Printable View"
    onclick={handlePDF}
  ></lightning-button>
</div>

<div class="slds-p-around_medium">
  <p class="slds-border_bottom">{dataSize} item : Filtered by {filter}</p>

  <lightning-datatable
    columns={columns}
    data={accs}
    hide-checkbox-column="true"
    key-field="id">
  </lightning-datatable>
</div>
```

**fslListViewCompo.js**

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";

import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from "@salesforce/schema/Account"; // import object
import AC_NAME from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Name"; // import fields
import AC_WEBSITE from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Website";
import AC_NUMBER from "@salesforce/schema/Account.AccountNumber";
import AC_INDUSTRY from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Industry";
import AC_RATING from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Rating";
import AC_PHONE from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Phone";
import AC_TYPE from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Type";

import ModalRecordEditForm from "c/modalRecordEditForm";

export default class FslListViewCompo extends LightningElement {
  accountObject = ACCOUNT_OBJECT; // object type
  accountFields = [
    AC_NAME,
    AC_WEBSITE,
    AC_NUMBER,
    AC_INDUSTRY,
    AC_RATING,
    AC_PHONE,
    AC_TYPE
  ]; // fields to be showin in form

  async showPopup() {
    const recordId = await ModalRecordEditForm.open({
      size: "small",
      accountFields: this.accountFields
    });

    if (recordId) {
      await this.showSuccessToast(recordId);
    }
  }

  async showSuccessToast(recordId) {
    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
      title: "Account created",
      message: "Record ID: " + recordId,
      variant: "success"
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
}
```

**Popup component with record form**

**modalRecordEditForm.html**

```
<template>
  <lightning-modal-header label="New Account"></lightning-modal-header>
  <lightning-modal-body>
    <div if:true={errors} class="slds-notify slds-notify_alert slds-alert_error">
      {errors}
    </div>
    <lightning-record-form
      object-api-name="Account"
      fields={accountFields}
      columns="2"
      onsuccess={closePopupSuccess}
      oncancel={closePopup}>
    </lightning-record-form>
  </lightning-modal-body>
</template>
```

**modalRecordEditForm.js**

```
import { api } from "lwc";
import LightningModal from "lightning/modal";

export default class ModalRecordEditForm extends LightningModal {
  @api accountFields;

  errors;

  closePopupSuccess(event) {
    this.close(event.detail.id);
  }

  closePopup() {
    this.close();
  }
}
```

**Demo**
[image]